# Do I need to do anything special before visiting the US on a 10-year multiple entry B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, multiple-entry

Last year I visited the US to go to a conference. I am a Romanian citizen, and I got a B1/B2 visa. To my surprise, the visa in my passport says it's valid for 10 years, and it has the **M** mark for multiple entries.

I want to visit the US next month, do I need to do anything special before leaving Europe, or do I just show up at the US border with my passport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to carry with you proof of your stay (and your return), and that you'll have enough funds to cover your trip; as you may get asked for it.

For example, the immigration officer might ask for:

1. Your return ticket.
2. Where you are staying?
3. How long do you plan on staying?
4. How you plan on supporting yourself?
5. What is the purpose of your trip?

Keep in mind that a visa is not a guarantee of entry, just permission to go knock on the door. So be prepared with documents that support your intended purpose of stay.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to show this; you just need to be prepared to show it if asked.  (Except for the "where are you staying" question; everyone including US citizens has to write an "address in the United States" on their customs form; for tourists this is the address of their first night's accommodations.

Comment: Yes good point; I'll clarify it some more.

Comment: I would swap the order. I have crossed the US border countless times and never got asked How you plan on supporting yourself? but always, always got asked, first and sometimes only question, What is the purpose of your trip?

Comment: Its not the order in which the questions are asked, its just a random selection of questions.

Answer (score 3):

10 years means you can use it for multiple entries during 10 years (and yes, European citizens who Need a visa normally get it for 10 years).

However, the actual time you can remain on each visit is usually 6 months